# Display custom avatar instead of OOTB in SharePoint Online programatically

Tags: sharepoint-online, sharepoint-enterprise, office-365, spfx, spfx-webparts

I am showing user profile pictures in my SharePoint portal for all logged in users. For the users who uploaded their pictures its showing fine, but for the users who do not uploaded their pictures its showing below image.

[image]

How i can set a custom avatar in my SPFX webpart if the user has not uploaded any photo?

Comment: Are you showing profile pictures in custom SPFx web part? Can you show the code you used for fetching and showing profile pictures in custom web part?

Comment: I am fetching it from https://contoso.sharepoint.com/_layouts/15/userphoto.aspx?size=L&username=adams@xyz.com